# Menu permissions problem

Tags: joomla-3.x

I have one menu that is associated to one group acess level.

This menu is not appearing if i acess an user with a different level of acess.

But this menu is appearing with none user logged in. I want to know what can i do to this menu only appears if users of that group acess logged in.

PS: Sorry for bad english.

Comment: Review your ACL and make sure that certain Usergroups have certain Access Levels and that there is no interfere with each other. Also look here for extensive [**ACL tutorial**](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Access_Control_List_Tutorial).

Answer (score 0):

User → user groups → viewing access levels → new → select the user group viewing access → give the tittle press save.
Then go to the menu you want to set the viewing access level as you created one.
Make the alteration and press save.
Then go to the module → choose the particular menu → set the access as you created one.
Press save and close.
Now visit to the site the particular menu only visible on specified users.